# Proper way of "shutdown" a spring context in J2SE

Tags: spring, java

I'm currently experiencing problems with a JPATransactionManager in a J2SE application.

The latest request was not properly saved in the database (surely a problem of cache).

This seems to be normal because the exit of the program does not seem to "cleanly" exit all Bean of the spring application context.

Do you know if there's a method of a clean shutdown a Spring context before exiting ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See also [Best way to force Spring shutdown from a bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401372), in particular, `AbstractApplicationContext.destroy()` and `AbstractApplicationContext.close()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Checkout [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-shutdown) manual on this topic.

Basically you need to call `registerShutdownHook()` on the application context.

Comment: Thank you. It works great !

It not solved me the problem of transaction but all object seems to be cleanly close.