# Best way to force Spring shutdown from a bean?

Tags: java, spring

My application uses a Spring `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` to process incoming messages. The main method of the app already registers a shutdown hook.

Question is this: what is the best way to force the application context to shut down?

If I throw a `RuntimeException` in the message listener, it is handled by the container, and not passed on. Is calling System.exit acceptable? Do I pass along the `ApplicationContext` to every class that needs to shut down, so I can call `close()` on it?

Comment: why do you need to shut down the application context?

Comment: Because the message listener can decide that it needs to; either because it has received an administration message asking the app to shut down, or because an abnormal condition has occurred. There are plenty of those, one of them is too many retries being received (this is a high volume system)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can cast your application context to `ConfigurableApplicationContext` and call `close()` on it. At least that's what happens when the context is shut down in a web-application environment, in cases the servlet context is destroyed.

If you want to get ahold of the `ApplicationContext`, your bean may implement [`ApplicationContextAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html)

Another option is to inject (or autowire with `@Autowired`) the application context:

```
@Inject
private ApplicationContext ctx;
```

Comment: How does the bean that needs to do the shutdown get the context? It's a POJO after all..

Comment: @xcut it depends on your application. Is it a web application, a desktop application?

Comment: Neither - a message queuing/routing system. So I guess the only way would be to pass the context to the bean, or implement an additional lifecycle interface of some sort?

Comment: @xcut no, just implement `ApplicationContextAware`

Comment: Or have the ApplicationContext injected directly. You do not need to implement ApplicationContextAware...