# Make failure start of Spring Context

Tags: spring

I have got some dynamic configuration for use different beans: since I take bean for name and class from DB i build a bean which check the integrity of context.

I add the annotation @PostConstruct and throw the exception NoSuchBeanDefinitionException but context not failed  to start.

`public class ActivityChannelCheckIntegrityImpl  {`

```
private static final transient Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( ActivityChannelCheckIntegrityImpl.class );

@Inject
private BeanListService beanListService;

@Inject
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    List<DynamicBean> dynamicBeans = beanListService .getDynamicBean();

    if ( dynamicBean== null )
        throw new RuntimeException( "no available bena" );
    else {
        boolean notFound = false;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( "Canali abilitati non presenti nel contesto" );
        for ( DynamicBean db : dynamicBeans ) {
            if ( !applicationContext.containsBean( db.getRealChannel() ) ) {
                if ( db.isEnable() ) {
                    logger.warn(
                            "*************** Il channel con nome {} non esiste ma e' stato abilitato! ***************",
                            db.getRealChannel() );
                    sb.append( " " ).append( db.getRealChannel() );
                    notFound = true;
                } else {
                    logger.error( "**** Non esiste il channel nel contesto con il nome {}", db.getRealChannel() );
                }
            } else {
                if ( !ac.isEnable() ) {
                    logger.warn( "*************** Il channel con nome {} non e' stato abilitato! ***************",
                            db.getRealChannel() );
                }
            }

        }
       if ( notFound ) {
            throw new NoSuchBeanDefinitionException( sb.toString() );
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How about `.close()` the `ApplicationContext` ?

Comment: There is not the method close on the ApplicationContext of spring. However I don't want close the context, I want fail to start context, so the application server know that the start is failed.

Comment: Have a look on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401372/best-way-to-force-spring-shutdown-from-a-bean